# Swift app for solving factors of numbers and display

Tags: ios, swift

i'm new the forum and also new to the swift language. I've been playing around with xcode and wanted to create an app that uses a fenceloop to display the factors of a number as a "solution." The app currently uses a label to display, a text for input, and a button to initiate. I have what i think to be functioning code but i can't see to get it to work because from what i understand, i have to convert the input that's a string into an int. If anyone has any ideas how to get this working; since i feel like i've done what i can.

The problem in particular i am getting is it is saying that "Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField!; to expected argument type 'Int'. What i intend to happen is that on the button click, it solves for the factors of whatever is in the text box and displays it as a string in the label. Any help is appreciated!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var input1 : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var label : UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func printFactors(n: Int) {
    var result: String = ""
    for i in 1...n {
        guard n % i == 0  else {continue}
        result += i == 1 ? "1" : " and \(i)"
    }
    print(result)

    let outputText = printFactors(n: input1)
    label.text = outputText
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Your IBAction can't have the signature you have at the moment. If there is a parameter, it must be the button.

Comment: any advice you/fixes you'd suggest or areas i should adjust? thank you for the heads up by the way!

Comment: It looks like you've connected the action target of your UITextField to the printFactors(n: Int) function. This is the wrong type signature for the target which will need to be something like printFactors(sender: AnyObject?). Then cast sender to an Int with something like let n = Int(sender).

Comment: @closetCoder No, you can't cast `sender` to an `Int`. Sender will be a `UIButton`.

Comment: @rmaddy, do you think you could show me what the fixes are in this case? are you able to edit my text on this website?

Comment: Well according to the error message it's a UITextField, so Int(sender.text!) should work.

Comment: @closetCoder But the `IBAction` is for the button handler so `sender` will be the button.

Comment: You are right, of course. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of issues and confusion in your `printFactors` method. Lets split it up and setup things properly.

First, make a separate method to do the math:

```
func calculateFactors(n: Int) -> String {
    var result: String = ""
    for i in 1...n {
        guard n % i == 0  else {continue}
        result += i == 1 ? "1" : " and \(i)"
    }
    print(result)

    return result    
}
```

Now lets setup the button action:

```
@IBAction func factorAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if let text = input1.text {
         if let num = Int(text) {
             let factor = calculateFactors(n: num)
             label.text = factor
         } else {
             // Show the user that the entered text isn't a number
         }
    } else {
         // There's no text
    }
}
```

Setup your button to use the new `factoryAction:` method instead of the old `printFactors:` method.

Comment: when you say set it up separately, do you mean as different files? or can i put it all in viewcontroller.swift?

Comment: You can put it in the same Swift file. It really depends on how it will be used. If more than one class needs to perform the same calculation I would suggest creating a "math util" class and putting your common math code there so it can be reused throughout your app.

Comment: so i pasted the @IBAction (i hope you dont mind that i did) and i got two errors. consequent declarations on the same line must be separated by a ';' and the other was "expected declaration." i'm running version 8.0 of xcode if that helps.

Comment: I had a typo - forgot the `func` keyword next to `factorAction` and had an extra colon (many years of Objective-c). See if that fixes it.

Comment: thank you so, so much. I see where i was going wrong in my attempt to simplify things. I've gone and connected the story board to the elements. It successfully compiles and launches; but when i enter "24," nothing displays in the label and i get a thread error on the line with "if let num = Int(text) {" - any idea why this would happen?

Comment: nevermind! once again, thank you so much rmaddy; i learned a lot. It seemed that my instance of xcode had an error in it and that was causing the thread issue. I restarted it and it worked!

Comment: any resources you'd recommend for really understanding the fundamentals of swift?

Comment: Sure. Start with Apple's [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book. Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

Can reduce this code down to two lines with some functional magic.

```
func factors(of number: Int) -> [Int] {
    return (1...number).filter { number % $0 == 0 }
}

print(factors(of: 24))
```

Comment: this will crash if `of number` is `0`. Maybe: `func factor(_ n: Int) -> [Int] { n != 0 ? (1...n).filter { n % $0 == 0 } : [] }`